# Return variables by reference in function parameters?

Tags: c++, memory

Let's say I have an arbitrary object `String`. I want to pass multiple `String`s back from a function. Can I do the following?

```
bool f(String &s1, String &s2) {
    if (worked) {
        s1 = String("abc");
        s2 = String("def");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Does this cause a memory corruption because I'm returning objects created locally?

Comment: No, it is a custom String class. And it doesn't matter if it "works" in the MWE because memory corruptions can cause problems later. I'd like to be sure.

Comment: You can simplify and slightly optimize that code by doing
`s1 = "abc";`. Then you don't even create any local object

Comment: Returning local variables is only bad when you return them _by value_. Besides, you're not _returning_ the temporary `String`s, you're assigning them to the objects passed as parameters, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @zenith You have it backwards. Returning local variables by value is fine. It's returning them by references that's a disaster.

Comment: @Ana You aren't returning objects created locally. What locally created object do you think you're returning? The only locally created objects I see are used to specify the value to set `s1` and `s2` to, and then they're not used again.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oops. I meant to write "by reference" instead of "by value". Or "only safe" instead of "only bad".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not returning objects created locally. The shown code returns a `bool` value.

What you're doing is assigning objects to passed references. There's nothing inherently wrong with that, either.

Comment: And, in fact, the most common reason you would pass by non-const reference is so that you can set the object's value in the function and have the changed value visible to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is perfectly valid. The assignment operator will be called for the specified type. (`String::operator=(const String &other)` or similar)

Comment: I tihnk you'll find it is the move-assignment operator